# DNS problem: How can I receive mail through google mail?

Tags: google, gmail, mail-server

Recently I wanted to host my own domain on my ubuntu server. I have configured bind with the following configuration file:

```
$ORIGIN tesa.com.ro.
$TTL 1800
@   IN  SOA ns1.tesa.com.ro. ticket.tesa.com.ro. (
            2009071804
            1800
            1h
            1w
            1h )
; Vanity DNS
@                      86400    IN NS    ns1.tesa.com.ro.
@                      86400    IN NS    ns2.tesa.com.ro.
; Vanity DNS must point to IP of ns1.nixcraft.net and ns2.nixcraft.net
ns1                    86400    IN A     89.238.232.245
ns2                    86400    IN A     89.238.232.245
; host stuff
@                      86400    IN A     89.238.232.245
www                    86400    IN A     89.238.232.245
ftp                    86400    IN A     89.238.232.245
mail               86400    IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
IN MX 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
IN MX 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
IN MX 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
IN MX 10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
IN MX 10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
IN MX 10 aspmx4.googlemail.com.
IN MX 10 aspmx5.googlemail.com.
```

However the mail won't work,it works when I want to send email but I am not able to receive email

Here is the diagnostics from google : https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/check?from=support.google.com&origin=checkmx-widget&domain=tesa.com.ro

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark here, but if the server is behind a firewall, did you forward the necessary POP ports? Otherwise did you try using a different connection. Ping your addresses to make sure you're receiving back... Hope I helped.